# Monitor the results of unit tests - Multiple Projects from different servers

Tags: unit-testing, charts, jenkins, hudson, rtc

I have the following situation:
Jenkins
  server1
     project1 - unit tests/build
     project2 - unit tests/build
     project3 - unit tests/build

server2
     project4 - unit tests/build
     project5 - unit tests/build
     project6 - unit tests/build

Hudson
  server3
     project7 - unit tests/build
     project8 - unit tests/build

RTC
  server4
     project9 - unit tests/build
     project10 - unit tests/build

Almost all the test are written in JUnit.
I need to collect all unit test results and display them in the same URL and create charts.
What do you suggest?What do I have to install?Can SONAR help me?

Thanks,
Anca

Answer (score 0):

I think the obvious answer is to move all of your builds to the same technology and the same server.  Is there a reason you can't do that?  Otherwise you'll just have another script or tool(s) to maintain.